# Two versions of git installed, currently using old one, how do I switch?

Tags: git, homebrew

I need some help, I had a version of git installed a while back (not sure how) not using homebrew. I just installed with homebrew and I'm not sure how to use the new one instead of the old one. Ideas? Thanks in advance

```
$ which -a git
/usr/local/bin/git
/usr/bin/git
/usr/local/bin/git

$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

$ /usr/bin/git --version
git version 1.7.5.4

$ /usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 1.8.4

$ git --version
git version 1.7.5.4
```

Comment: use absolute paths, or edit your $PATH to make the directory of whichever version you want to use show up FIRST in the path.

Comment: I just deleted the git files from the folder/version I didn't want/need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Should I uninstall the git in `/usr/bin/git` or just leave it there? I believe I install it when installing cmd line tools. If so, how should I uninstall properly?