# I have two versions of Git and old one being used. How can I fix it?

Tags: git, version-control, path, atlassian-sourcetree

For a historical reason, I have two versions of git on my Windows 10 machine.

> $ where git C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\mingw32\bin\git.exe
>       C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

The former being used by SourceTree somehow, but it's quite outdated (2.7.4).
The latter is up to date (2.17.1.2).

- How do I uninstall the older version?
- How do I use the new version for my version control?

I guess it's about PATH setting somewhere, but I have no idea.

This is related, but for other platforms I think.
[Two versions of git installed, currently using old one, how do I switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231747/two-versions-of-git-installed-currently-using-old-one-how-do-i-switch)

I looked at this, but did not help.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/installing-and-upgrading-git-776640906.html#InstallingandupgradingGit-InstallorupgradeGitonWindows

Comment: You can uninstall the old git version directly, and add the path to the new git version to environment variables. Then check the git version used by sourcetree: Tools -> Options -> Git Tab -> check the system git version sourcetree used (https://ibb.co/bXTyzd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of

`echo %PATH%`

included `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`, i.e., the new version. So I guess there must be something overriding PATH for SourceTree.

Then I thought it can be SourceTree preference. Tools > Options > Git tab has **Git Version** pane, where you can choose either '**Embedded**' or '**System**'. In my case "Embedded' was chosen. And there is '**Update Embedded**' button right next to it. And that button did the job!

[image]

I realized that the Git version is too old by a notification from SourceTree but it did not tell me where and how to update it.

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can mark your answer.

Comment: Actually I need to wait for a few more hours to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your linked question has correct answer - you need to update your PATH variable.

From terminal make sure that incorrect git.exe is in current PATH:

```
echo %PATH%
```

Then copy result, replace old git with new one, and update PATH:

```
set PATH=<updatedpath>
```

If you are using git from some GUI tool, it's possible that in configuration it stores path to git.exe somewhere, you need to find this option and update it too.

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious why did you bother changing the code block in my original question? At least `where git` is a command, and I thought the output was easier to read in monospace font. Is it a custom in StackOverflow?

Comment: @JohnSmith for me it looked like 3 different blocks as lines were separated by whitespaces, I decided that single quote block look nicer. The general rule here - if you think that you can improve something - do it :)